# Stateless REST API using CakePHP 2

Tags: rest, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I am working on creating a REST API + Javascript client using CakePHP 2. I would like the javascript client to ask the user for its user and password and then use this information for issuing REST requests to the CakePHP REST app.

So I am thinking I will need to send the authentication info with every REST Request and that authentication can be done on every request on the CakePHP side. So my question is: how do I do such a thing with CakePHP? Should I use Basic Authentication? If so, how do I make sure no session is used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Basic** authentication, **digest** authentication or **building your authentication object**

By using one of those, no sessions will be created. no need to make sure of this, I think this is done automatically by cake.

Refer to this [article (Authentication chapter in cakePHP book)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) for more information.